# vertically align img inside floated div

Tags: javascript, html, css

There are 5 floated `div`s which heights are stretched to 100% of `document` height using Javascript. All 5 of them contain `img` element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="static"><img src="http://www.rs.dhamma.org/wheel.gif"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://www.rs.dhamma.org/wheel.gif"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://www.rs.dhamma.org/wheel.gif"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://www.rs.dhamma.org/wheel.gif"/></div>
        <div class="clear"><img src="http://www.rs.dhamma.org/wheel.gif"/></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>​
```

Javascript:

```
//sets columns height to 100%;
function colsHeight(){
        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        $("#wrapper div").height(docHeight);
};

$(document).ready(function(){
    colsHeight();
    });
```

and CSS:

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;    
    }

#wrapper{
 width: 1000px;
 margin: 0 auto;    
    }

    #wrapper div{    
        padding: 0 20px;
        background-color: #9F81F7;        
        float: left;
        border-right: 1px solid black;
    }
    #wrapper img{

    }

div.clear:after{
    content: " ";
    clear: both;
    }
```

​I've tried setting parent's `div` `display: table` and `img` `display: table-cell, vertical-align: middle` but no luck. Defining `margin-top: 50%` is acting anything but expected.

[**JSFIDDLE HERE!!!**](http://jsfiddle.net/3gqcS/1/)

Any help appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use display: inline-block; instead of floats? Then you can use vertical-align 'til your heart's content.

Comment: Have already tried that but with no success. Try editing my JSFIDDLE and check it for youself. Thanks

Comment: Also if you plan on using `display:inline-block;` you must leave no spaces in-between the `#wrapper div`s. _ _ i.e. all on one line or without indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could position them absolutely, then set `top: 50%` and `margin-top: -63px`. Of course, this only works if you know the height of the image (`126px` in your case). If the image sizes are dynamic, the easiest, but yucky way would be to set the margin-top on the images using js after they are loaded.

Anyway, the static method can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/3gqcS/2/

Answer (score 2):

since you using javascript and jQuery(can't live without him) you can do....

check this: http://jsfiddle.net/828pW/

here is the code:

```
function verticalAlignImage(img)
{
    if(img.height)
    {

        $(img).css({
            position:'absolute',
            top: ($(img).parent().height() - img.height)/2
        }).parent().css('position', 'relative');

    }
    else 
    {
        setTimeout(function(){

            verticalAlignImage(img);
        }, 100);
    }
}
```

​

Comment: Thanks man!! Nice Javascript code!! Who learnt you that? Cheers man!!

Answer (score 2):

This feels a bit dirty, but you can set the div's line-height to div height + image height then overflow:hidden

```
<div id="static" style="height: 481px; line-height: 607px; overflow: hidden;">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the columns:

```
    position:relative;
    width:<width>;/* width must be set */
```

and the images as:

```
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto 0;
```

That should perfectly center them however then you need to set column width as the image with absolute positioning take up no space at all.

Also, instead of using java script just add:

```
    html, body, #wrapper, #wrapper div{height:100%;}
```

instead.

Learned from: http://www.tutwow.com/htmlcss/quick-tip-css-100-height/

Comment: what browser are you using, that it does not work? @daniel.tosaba

Comment: aligning that way doesn't work. but browser trick is awesome. using latest chrome & firefox

Comment: @daniel.tosaba I just whipped up a demo that works for me; can you see it?  http://jsbin.com/iworeh **EDIT** updated link

Comment: It must have been some mess in my code that was affecting it then. Will take a look. It is a great technique.

Comment: I added the `margin:auto;` in an edit after posting so you probably just tried it before then. Good Luck.